# Proof-of-Stake: How to ensure immutability of the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hash, proof-of-work, proof-of-stake, block-hash

In Proof-of-Work, a miner tries to solve PoW puzzle based on the hash of previous block, such that in case of changing block `B_i`, all blocks after that (blocks `B_i+1`, `B_i+2`, ...) are no longer valid since puzzle of every block has been solved based on the hash of previous block.

Now, in a scheme without mining consensus such as Proof-of-Stake, does a validator have to use/insert the hash of previous block, `B_i`, in the new block, `B_i+1` ?

**If yes, How ?**

And **if No**, how are blocks **chained** such that in case of **changing** a block, `B_i`, all blocks after this modified block will become **invalid**? We would need to chain blocks to each other to ensure immutability of the data stored in the blockchain.